# mvc3 httpResponse.write

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, logging, partial-views, httpresponse

I have some partial views that are rendered sequentially. I would like to create a log of what has rendered successfully on the top of the page, when the last partial view has completed. The only way I can think of, is to keep an array of log details and then display the log detail in a partial view on the top of the page, using a rendersection.

This to me seems cumbersome, I would prefer to be able to use HttpResponse.Write to display it to the page. However this way I don't seem to be able to control the ordering of where my log will appear on the screen. I would like them to be displayed in the same location on the page. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put div in the top of the page and every Partial View write to that div?

```
<div id=log > <label id="logs"> The Log: </label> </div>     

$('#logs').after('what you want1'); // from partial 1
$('#logs').after('what you want2'); // from partial 2
$('#logs').after('what you want3'); // from partial 3
$('#logs').after('what you want4'); // from partial 4
```

Pass the partial view the data you want to "log"  in the Model\ [ViewBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) and start logging!

Comment: thanks for encouraging a bit of outside the box thinking. For now, I am trying to keep this on the server side, looking at @RenderSection to see if that might work